# How to set starting and ending point for line projection in DM script

Tags: dm-script

I am trying to draw line projection for an image . The line 4 in the code below `sy/2` represents the length of projection (here is the half image range). But how to set the starting point or ending point with scripting? For example, I want to draw the line projection, from 1/4 image range to 3/4 image range. Any suggestions?

```
image src := getfrontimage()
number sx,sy
src.GetSize(sx,sy)
image line_projection := RealImage( "Vertical", 4, sy/2 )
line_projection[irow,0] += src
line_projection *= 1/sx
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing to only look at the image area you are interested in. For "clipping" the source to the interesting part use `img[y1, x1, y2, x2]`.

```c
image src := getFrontImage();
number width, height;
src.GetSize(width, height);

number start_y = 1/4 * height;
number end_y = 3/4 * height;

image line_projection := RealImage("Vertical", 4, width);
line_projection[icol, 0] += src[start_y, 0, end_y, width];
line_projection *= 1/(height/2);

line_projection.ShowImage();
```

Comment: I do believe you've mixed up some coordinates in your example. For a vertical sum, the image should be "width" sized and the iteration should go over icol now irow.
Also, the notation in GMS is img[x,y] for points, but img[y1,x1,y2,x2] for areas. I know, that is strange, but it is as historically grown notation following "top/left/bottom/right" corner nomination.

Comment: One can avoid the [t,l,b,r] notation by using the command 'slice2()'. That command is clearer. (Except, that it assume the image is 3D so you need to specify three startng point coordinates!) 'sliceN()' is the most clear, but also most verbose command, speciying both input and output dimensionality.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for pointing it out. I used the example and changed only some parts. And I tested with a noise image which obviously doesn't show errors when directions are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While using intrinsic variables (`icol`,`irow`,...) for iterative summing was the fasted method in GMS 1, this is no longer true for newer versions that utilize multi-threaded code, as demonstrated by the following example:

```c
// various ways to sum a subsection of an image
number sx = 4096, sy = 4096
number startx = 0.2, starty = 0.2
number endx = 0.8, endy = 0.4

// Coordinates of cut
number t = trunc(starty*sy), l = trunc(startx*sx), b = trunc(endy*sy), r = trunc(endx*sx)
image test := realImage( "Test", 4, sx, sy )

test = sin( icol/iwidth * 20*Pi()) + cos( itheta * iradius/iwidth * 50)
test= sin( icol/iwidth * 20*Pi())
test.ShowImage()

ROI marker = NewROI()
marker.ROISetLabel( "Section" )
marker.ROISetRectangle( t, l, b, r )
marker.ROISetVolatile( 0 )
test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplayAddRoi( marker )

//OKDialog( "Performing vertical sum with various methods now." )
number h = b - t
number w = r - l

ClearResults()
number ts, te, tps = GetHighResTicksPerSecond()

// using intrinsic variables
image sumImg1 := RealImage( "Sum intrinsic", 4, w )
ts = GetHighResTickcount()
sumImg1[icol, 0] += test[t,l,b,r];
te = GetHighResTickcount()

sumImg1.ShowImage()
result("\n Summing using intrinisic variables: " + (te-ts)/tps + " sec")

// using for-loop of slice
image sumImg2 := RealImage( "Sum with slice", 4, w )
ts = GetHighResTickcount()
for( number i=0; i<h; i++)
    sumImg2 += test.slice1(0,i,0, 0,w,1)
te = GetHighResTickcount()

sumImg2.ShowImage()
result("\n Summing using for-loop with slice : " + (te-ts)/tps + " sec")

// using project of slice
image sumImg3 := RealImage( "Sum with project", 4, w )
ts = GetHighResTickcount()
sumImg3 = test[t,l,b,r].project( 1 )
te = GetHighResTickcount()

sumImg3.ShowImage()
result("\n Summing using project on section  : " + (te-ts)/tps + " sec")
```